# Meteor data contexts - data not available inside template #each

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to compare two variables to see if they match.

This is to decide if I need a `selected` attr on an `<option>`.

The template looks like this:

```
    <select>
        <option disabled>Please choose...</option>
        {{#each themes}}
            <option {{selected}}>{{this.themeName}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
```

In the template helper I set a `currentTheme` var like so:

```
currentTheme: function() {
    return this.theme;
}
```

The trouble is that `this` here is different to `this` within the `#each` loop above and placing `{{currentTheme}}` inside the `#each` renders nothing. Basically, I can't compare `currentTheme` with `this.themeName` to see if they are the same because one is always undefined :(

So... I'm wondering what I would have to do inside

```
selected: function() {
    // ???
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in this [Discover Meteor blog post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/), since Meteor 0.8 you can pass the parent context as an argument to a template helper using the `..` keyword.

```
<select>
    <option disabled>Please choose...</option>
    {{#each themes}}
        <option {{selected ..}}>{{this.themeName}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

```js
selected: function(parentContext) {
  return this.themeName === parentContext.theme ? "selected" : '';
}
```

In this case, the `currentTheme` template helper would be unnecessary if you're using it just for this functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I did read that but your rewrite of my code concreted my understanding. Maybe it's my misunderstanding of data contexts versus variable scope, but surely the child should inherit the parent context like standard variable scope in js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UI._parentData()`:

```
selected: function() {
    // ???
    var dataOutsideEach = UI._parentData(1);

    if(currentTheme && this.theme) return "selected";

}
```

If that doesn't work, try removing the '1' and placing '0' or '2' instead (not quite sure about which). The integer represents the number of parent views to look for the data context through.

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing the accepted answer is a newer interface for this.